# Any possibility of directory change when update app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

Recently, updated my app v1.0 to v1.0.1.
Then one of our tester said

> 'Lost all pictures that saved in app' (not photo library)

I found that installing the App with Xcode and updating the AppStore version on the device
will change the App's directory, so data will be lost. (But not all data. Some files are copied, in my case .db files. that's really odd)

ex)

> /var/mobile/Applications/D108B86A-27A8-4665-A490-F1CBB94CE04A/Documents/
>   /var/mobile/Applications/CCCD0C25-C33E-498F-8D24-9AF243E01A21/Documents/

But it isn't normal process, maybe it causes problem.

Is there any possibility of directory change in normal process?(Install from appstore then update from appstore)

I wanna try 'Normal process' but there's no device that have old ver.
So can't make appear 'Update' button in appstore again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that updating app causes directory changed.

So should not save 'Full Path' at Database or file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: ad-hoc version of app can't upgrade to appstore version. It just removes ad-hoc and installs app store. But during normal update process app store -> app store it replaces only app package so all should work OK.